# Preserve my character encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character

i bought the domain xn--79n.ws which resolves to ∠.ws. (Still counts as one character on twitter)

I built a custom image upload service and i am trying to echo back the link. Instead of echoing back http://xn--79n.ws/image.jpg, i want to echo back http://∠.ws/image.jpg.

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do us add a proper Header to your HTML output and it would work

HTML > HEAD

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Or

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Thanks

:)